# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: apache2, mysql, bugzilla

I have installed apache2 and mysql-server-5.6 on linux ubuntu 14.04, when i browse ip address apache is working fine, but mysql is not running--> I have run commands `sudo service mysql start` or `service mysql restart` from the terminal, then output is came like this start: `Job failed to start.`
Can anybody help me about this issue, how to connect mysql.

Before this I have installed Xampp server on same system and already made it stop using `/opt/lamp/lamp stop` command.

Comment: Have a look at /var/log/syslog and add relevant lines from upstart and mysql to your post

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before. I have tried installing LAMP on Ubuntu over and and over again, and after a while, MySQL gave that error. I looked all over the web for a solution to the problem, and nothing worked. Eventually I found out that the server didn't have enough swap (VSwap) space to connect to MySQL, and /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock was removed. There are many ways displayed on the internet for how to increase swap in KVM, and other full virtualization types.

If you use OpenVZ, there is a specific way to do this.

1. Make sure you have vzctl v. 3.0.30 or newer.
2. Run this command:

   ```
   $ sudo vzctl set 777 --ram 512M --swap 1G --save
   ```

   If it can't find the command "vzctl", run

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install vzctl
   ```

   That  should fix your issue. If it doesn't work, click [here](https://redirect.viglink.com/?key=bb299217e2c08d8463f4fcbb9f7f2743&u=https%3A%2F%2Fopenvz.org%2FVSwap) for more information about VSwap.